# How can I vendorize Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have a git submodule of git://github.com/rails/rails in `vendor/rails` of my Rails 3 app. This is where an unpacked/vendorized Rails would go prior to 3.0.

How do I instruct my Gemfile that `vendor/rails` is the correct location, and not my system-wide rails install?

---

So, some people have noted that you can do simply:

```
gem 'rails', :path => "vendor/rails"
```

You can also include a version number, e.g.,

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3', :path => "vendor/rails"
```

Both of these depend on what you actually have in `vendor/rails`. For example, if I do `git checkout v3.0.3` in `vendor/rails`, both of these will work fine on their own (3.0.3 is the current).

But if I use a beta instead, I seem to [need to add some additional dependencies](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2010/11/15/edge-rails-pro-tip/):

```
gem 'rails', :path => "vendor/rails"
gem 'arel',  :git => 'git://github.com/rails/arel.git'
gem 'rack',  :git => 'git://github.com/rack/rack.git'
```

I could also extract these into `vendor` as git submodules, I suppose, and again use `:path`.

Do be aware that rack comes from `rack/rack` on github, not `rails/rack`. The latter is a fork and hasn't been updated since 2009. I made this mistake and spent hours fixing it.

If you've got older versions of rails installed on your machine, you may also need to take care to use `script/rails` instead of the `rails` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just `gem 'rails', '3.0.3', :path => "vendor/rails"` in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', :path => "vendor/rails"
```

Comment: Doesn't Rails look for itself in the vendor folder before it looks for the system wide copy??

Comment: @Zabba: No, by default Bundler is used to load the directory where Rails is. You must be explicit in this fashion to be able to have it at vendor/rails.

Comment: What is the effect of including version, as @ziggurism did?

Comment: @mohawkjohn, including the version number means that that version of the gem will be used/vendorized